# Saving values when refresh a page

Tags: grails, groovy

I made a drop down list

```
<g:form action="index" method="GET">
     <div class="fieldcontain">
         <label for="query">Where:</label>
         <g:select value="${params.parameter}" name="parameter" from="${Trip.list()}" noSelection="['':'All parameter']"/>
         <g:actionSubmit action="index" value="Find" />
      </div>
</g:form>
```

But when I select a value and press the submit button, the selected value comes to the server, but the selected value remains in the list by default

Controller

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 2, 10)

    def parameterList = Parameter.createCriteria().list(params) {

        if (params.parameter != "") {
            bank {
                eq "parameter", "${params.parameter}"
            }
        }

    }

    [parameterList: parameterList, parameterTotal: parameterList.totalCount, params: params]
}
```

How to make it so that the selected value is displayed after reloading the page?

I use: | Grails Version: 3.2.10
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10

Comment: actionSubmit vs submitButton please read up about actionSubmit

Comment: I was reading. I think that there I have no problems
I should just select from the list only those that satisfy the selected value

Comment: It is possibly because you are using some custom map to select from, usually you define optionKey and optionValue which bind to given domain object result set - the default value by default is then selected upon submission. Maybe you need to look at jquery select by querying value of input id. Try it on a typical domain class and see if that works

Comment: What does a typical domain class mean? And somehow it is possible to do without jquery? Standard tools?

Comment: `<g:select value="${SomeDomainClass.get(2L)?.someField}" from="${SomeDomainClass.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="someField"  />` where you select your g select from a valid domain class bind the optionKey and value of the fields you are collecting in that class and the value to be the optionValues field you are collecting - if something doesn't work try the basic examples of g:select as very clearly shown on the guides here https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

Comment: Does not work(((

Comment: please edit question and provide the grails version you are using